# how do I reference a list array I created in a different class into a another 2

Tags: java, search, arraylist

This is where i created the arraylist

```
package sample;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import sample.Data.Students;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudentEnrollment {

    public static ArrayList<Students> SDetails=new ArrayList<Students>();


    public static String StuID="";


    @FXML
    private Button studentenrollmentnextbtn;

    @FXML
    private TextField studentenrollmentname;

    @FXML
    private TextField studentenrollmentid;

    @FXML
    private TextField studentenrollmentage;

    @FXML
    private TextField studentenrollmentnum;

    public void StudentEnroll(ActionEvent m)throws IOException{

        Students s=new Students();
        s.setSname(studentenrollmentname.getText());
        s.setSid(studentenrollmentid.getText());
        StuID=studentenrollmentid.getText();
        s.setSage(Integer.parseInt(studentenrollmentage.getText()));
        s.setSnumber(Integer.parseInt(studentenrollmentnum.getText()));
        SDetails.add(s);


        Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AdminEnterDetails.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage= (Stage)((Node)m.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

and this is my student class

```
package sample.Data;

public class Students {

    private String Sid;
    private String Sname;
    private int Sage;
    private int Snumber;


    public String getSid() {
        return Sid;
    }

    public void setSid(String sid) {
        Sid = sid;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return Sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        Sname = sname;
    }

    public int getSage() {
        return Sage;
    }

    public void setSage(int sage) {
        Sage = sage;
    }

    public int getSnumber() {
        return Snumber;
    }

    public void setSnumber(int snumber) {
        Snumber = snumber;
    }

}
```

this is where i want to use the arraylist,i want use it here because,i want to check whether my arraylist is empty,if its empyt i want to show a error message and if its not empty i want to search the ID that i entered in that arraylist

```
public class StudentLogin {

    StudentEnrollment = new StudentEnrollment();
    ArrayList<Students> list = number.getList();

    @FXML
    private Label error;
    @FXML
    private TextField studentuserid;
    @FXML
    private Button studentloginbtn;


    public void ViewbyStudent(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {

        if()
        for(Students m:StudentEnrollment.SDetails)
            if(Objects.equals(m.getSid(),studentuserid.getText())){

                Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ViewStudentDetails.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                Stage stage= (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();

            }else{
                error.setText("Student ID you entered is incorrec,\n or ID couldn't be found,PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Java coding convention follows camel case. For example, your variable `SDetails` should be [camel-cased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) as `sDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

StudentEnrollment.SDetails.isEmpty();

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. ArrayLists have a built in `isEmpty()` method that will return a boolean value true/false depending whether or not the list is empty.

So, assuming that your empty `if()` is where you need your logic to go, your `ViewbyStudent()` method would look something like this:

```
public void ViewbyStudent(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {

    if(!studentEnrollment.SDetails.isEmpty()) {
        for (Students m : StudentEnrollment.SDetails)
            if (Objects.equals(m.getSid(), studentuserid.getText())) {

                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ViewStudentDetails.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();

            } else {
                error.setText("Student ID you entered is incorrec,\n or ID couldn't be found,PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
            }
    } else {
        error.setText("Oh no! SDetails is empty!");
    }
}
```

So basically if the list is **NOT** empty (that's what the ! is) it will execute the code block you already had, but now if the list **IS** empty it will simply set the text to "Oh no! SDetails is empty!"